# Nested List<> property for abstract class

Tags: c#, list, generics, abstract-class

Thank you for your replies which are excellent. However on reading into HashPsi initial comment in much greater depth, I have discovered that several users all want to use this app with several different but very similar reports for instance there are a larger number columns available which can be included/removed in any report specific to the user.

Rather than make a solution for each user type, each user can simply view their data and select filters which initially importing it.
To keep it very simple in the below edit at the row level I have set a very simple id and 20x Strings, then List pre-parse's currency/numbers, which can be used to select dropdown number filters, or ranges between values.  A similar List is used for dropdowns of strings at sheet level.

The finished application will use one database seperated by sheet id(or similar).
What are your thoughts here, and should I use more generics like the examples below(which are excellent, if a little advanced as Im still a poor nooby :) ).

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }//todo - autoincrement
}

class Sheet
{
    public List<Row> Rows { get; set; }
    public List<ParsedToStringList> ParsedStringLists { get; set; }
}

public class Row : Entity
{
    public int RowId { get; set; } //unique key
    public string String1 { get; set; }
    public string String2 { get; set; }
    public string String3 { get; set; }
    public string String4 { get; set; }
    public string String5 { get; set; }
    public string String6 { get; set; }
    public string String7 { get; set; }
    public string String8 { get; set; }
    public string String9 { get; set; }
    public string String10 { get; set; }

    public string String11 { get; set; }
    public string String12 { get; set; }
    public string String13 { get; set; }
    public string String14 { get; set; }
    public string String15 { get; set; }
    public string String16 { get; set; }
    public string String17 { get; set; }
    public string String18 { get; set; }
    public string String19 { get; set; }
    public string String20 { get; set; }
    public List<ParsedToNumber> ParsedNumbers { get; set; }
}

public class ParsedToNumber
{
    public int ColumnPosition { get; set; }
    public decimal Number { get; set; }
    public int RowId { get; set; } //Foreign key
}

public class ParsedToStringList
{
    public int ColumnPosition { get; set; }
    public List<Filter> FilteredStrings { get; set; }
    public int RowId { get; set; } //Foreign key
}

public class Filter
{
    public string FilterString { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var sheet=new Sheet();
        sheet.Rows.Add(new Row(){
            Id = 1, RowId = 303, String1 = "ABC123", String2 = "Abc Ltd", String3 = "£550.00",
            String4 = "£150.00", String5 = "Wholesale", ParsedNumbers = new List<ParsedToNumber>(){
                new ParsedToNumber() {ColumnPosition = 3, Number = 550.00m, RowId = 303},
                new ParsedToNumber() {ColumnPosition = 4, Number = 150.00m, RowId = 303}
            } });
        sheet.Rows.Add(new Row(){
            Id = 2, RowId = 607, String1 = "XYZ808", String2 = "XYZ Unlimited", String3 = "£999.99",
            String4 = "£55.55", String5 = "Wholesale", ParsedNumbers = new List<ParsedToNumber>() {
                new ParsedToNumber() {ColumnPosition = 3, Number = 999.99m, RowId = 607},
                new ParsedToNumber() {ColumnPosition = 4, Number = 55.55m, RowId = 607}
            } });

        //This provides for persistance of the data in string format
        //and conversion of columns which can be parsed are created 
        //ready for future in dropdown or range selections .

    }
}
```

I really played around with this and need fresh eyes on it.  I presume that I can change the List Cells within class Row to something that I can cast with concrete objects inherited from abstract class Cell.

The goal of the code is to create a dynamic row of cells which can be parsed into integer, currency, string(and other) types if possible and used by the user. The data is imported from a csv file from an accounting data source.
I had originally created a set number of integer, currency, string fields which is inefficient but simpler(if this approach is better please say).

```
class Sheet
{
    public List<Row> Rows { get; set; }
}

public class Row
{
    public string Dummy { get; set; }
    public List<Cell> Cells { get; set; }//Intellisence at <Cell> advises 
}                                        //incorrect number of type parameters?

public class Column
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public enum ColumnType
{
    String,
    Number,
    Currency
}

public abstract class Cell<T>
{
    public Column Column { get; set; }
    public T Data { get; set; }

    public abstract void Parse( object obj );
}

public class StringCell : Cell<string>
{
    public override void Parse( object obj )
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: It is safe to assume that a column will contain all cells of the same type (integer, real, string, ...)?

Comment: You could handle the parsing of the data into the cell by relying on a new ColumnType property for the Column class. As the time when you use the data, you cannot avoid switching on the type, recorded either at the level of the columns or the cell.

Comment: I've read this a couple times and understand the intent...but please forgive me...what exactly is the question?

Comment: So you want to know how to define the property `public List<Cell<?>> Cells` when `Cells<>` is a generic type. You can't. You either make `Cell` generic also, or use `object` types only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are usually 2 main considerations to keep in mind when creating an object model to represent a table/spreadsheet:

1. The parsing of the spreadsheet into an object model. At that level, the type of value expected for a column should dictate how the cell is constructed.
2. Use of the object model (manipulation and transformation of the data, rendering to a UI). At that level, the client code will almost certainly need to distinguish between the different types of values allowed for a column (i.e., this code will need to switch on the value type for the cell/column). For example, formatting of a cell data in a UI will need to know whether the cell holds a text, a number, or a currency amount. Therefore, a completely generic Cell model will be of no use.

To facilitate the utility of the model for the parsing and subsequent use, you could use a factory for cells that creates cells based on a value type associated to the column. For downstream use of the cells, you can have methods that return the value held by the cell for each of the possible types (string, int, decimal).

Something like this:

```
class Sheet {
  public List<Row> Rows { get; set; }
}

public class Row {
  public string Dummy { get; set; }
  public List<Cell> Cells { get; set; } 
}                                        

public class Column {
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public ValueType ValueType { get; set; }
}

public class Cell {
  public Column Column { get; private set; }
  public object Data { get; private set; }

  public int GetValueInt() {
    return Column.ValueType == ValueType.Number ? (int)Data : 0;
  }

  public string GetValueString() {
    // could also return Data.ToString() is Data is not null
    return Column.ValueType == ValueType.String ? (string)Data : null;
  }

  public decimal GetValueCurrenty() {
    return Column.ValueType == ValueType.Currency ? (decimal)Data : 0;
  }

  // factory for cells
  public static Cell MakeCell(object data, Column column) {

    // fail-early if the data does not match the value type specified by the column
    switch (column.ValueType) {
        case ValueType.String:
        if (!(data is string)) {
          throw new ArgumentException("Invalid data for column containing strings");
        }
        break;

        case ValueType.Number:
        if (!(data is int)) {
          throw new ArgumentException("Invalid data for column containing ints");
        }
        break;

        case ValueType.Currency:
        if (!(data is decimal)) {
          throw new ArgumentException("Invalid data for column containing decimals");
        }
        break;
   }

  var cell = new Cell { Column = column, Data = data };
  return cell;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, but it will require you to box your value types:

```
public class Row
{
    public string Dummy { get; set; }
    public List<Cell<Object>> Cells { get; set; } 
}
```

But IMHO this is messy in that you always have to check the type of object in your cell through casting. It would be better if your cell content identifies the type of content it has. I think this is what you were already trying to do. I would start with a base class for my cell content:

```
public abstract class ContentBase
{
    public ContentType Type;
    public Object Value;
}
```

Note that `ContentType` is your `ColumnType` except renamed. Then you could have your `StringContent` like this... (You can change the implementation of `set` as you need.)

```
public class StringContent : ContentBase
{
    private string _value;
    public ContentType Type 
    {
        get { return ContentType.String; } 
        private set;
    }
    public string Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set { _value = (string)value; }
    }
}
```

Now, you can leave your `Cell` to not worry about its content (so you probably may not need to have it as `abstract`).

```
public abstract class Cell<>
{
    public Column Column { get; set; }
    public ContentBase Content { get; set; }
}
```

And have your `Row` simpler like this:

```
public class Row
{
    public string Dummy { get; set; }
    public List<Cell> Cells { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `int` `Date` and `string` do not share a common type other than `object` you can't use generics with this model.

Consider creating a common interfase `IValue` for all the cell value types and proceed from there:

```
public enum ColumnType
{
    String,
    Date,
    Currency
}

public interface IValue
{
    void Parse(object obj);
}

public class Sheet
{
    public List<Column> Columns { get; set; }
    public Column this[int column] { get { return Columns[column]; } set { Columns[column]=value; } }
}

public class Column
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ColumnType Type { get; set; }
    public List<Cell> Rows { get; set; }
    public Cell this[int row] { get { return Rows[row]; } set { Rows[row]=value; } }
}

public class Cell
{
    public Column Column { get; set; }
    public IValue Data { get; set; }
}

public class StringValue : IValue
{
    public StringValue(string value) { Value=value; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public void Parse(object obj)
    {
        Value=obj.ToString();
    }
}
public class DecimalValue : IValue
{
    public DecimalValue(decimal value) { Value=value; }
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
    public void Parse(object obj)
    {
        if(obj is decimal)
        {
            Value=(decimal)obj;
        }
    }
}
public class DateValue : IValue
{
    public DateValue(DateTime value) { Value=value; }
    public DateTime Value { get; set; }
    public void Parse(object obj)
    {
        if(obj is DateTime)
        {
            Value=(DateTime)obj;
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var sheet=new Sheet() { Columns = new List<Column>() };
        sheet.Columns.Add(new Column()
        {
            Type=ColumnType.String,
            Name="Item",
            Rows=new List<Cell>()
        });
        sheet.Columns.Add(new Column()
        {
            Type=ColumnType.Date,
            Name="Date",
            Rows=new List<Cell>()
        });
        sheet.Columns.Add(new Column()
        {
            Type=ColumnType.Currency,
            Name="Amount",
            Rows=new List<Cell>()
        });
        sheet[0].Rows.Add(new Cell() { Column=sheet[0], Data=new StringValue("AAB") });
        sheet[0].Rows.Add(new Cell() { Column=sheet[0], Data=new StringValue("AAC") });
        sheet[0].Rows.Add(new Cell() { Column=sheet[0], Data=new StringValue("ABA") });

        sheet[1].Rows.Add(new Cell() { Column=sheet[1], Data=new DateValue(DateTime.Now) });
        sheet[1].Rows.Add(new Cell() { Column=sheet[1], Data=new DateValue(DateTime.Now) });
        sheet[1].Rows.Add(new Cell() { Column=sheet[1], Data=new DateValue(DateTime.Now) });

        sheet[2].Rows.Add(new Cell() { Column=sheet[2], Data=new DecimalValue(1000m) });
        sheet[2].Rows.Add(new Cell() { Column=sheet[2], Data=new DecimalValue(1200m) });
        sheet[2].Rows.Add(new Cell() { Column=sheet[2], Data=new DecimalValue(870m) });

        sheet[0][1].Data.Parse("CCC");

        var check=(sheet[0][1].Data as StringValue).Value;
        // check == "CCC"
    }
}
```

To make your life easier, I would create you own collections instead of using `List<Cell>` and `List<Column>` that would implement methods like `AddColumn()` and `AddCells()`. You would have to inherit from `System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<>`.